# How to make a list of all Spanish words

Tags: python, list

All I need is to have a list (in Python) consisting of all words in Spanish. Once I have that, I will be running some scripts using this list, but building the list is proving to be more difficult than I expected. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you expecting the Spanish words to come from?

Comment: I have imported cess_esp from nltk, for instance, but the object I get is not a list but some other kind of object I cannot transform into a simple list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We expect a clear, specific, direct question; "Thank you for any help" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Also: did you try to read the documentation? What kind of object do you get? According to the documentation, what kinds of things can you do with it? [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to [look for](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+get+list+of+spanish+words) an existing solution?

Comment: here are some to help you ["hola", "amigo", "que", "tal", "esternocleidomastoideo"], the last one is the longest spanish word

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [raw list of spanish words](https://github.com/lorenbrichter/Words/blob/master/Words/es.txt) I've found.

You can download the file and import them in python to put them into a list.

```
with open(spanish.txt) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in lines]
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Can also read it from github with requests.

import requests


def convert_string(string):
    li = list(string.split(","))
    return li

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/words/an-array-of-spanish-words/master/index.json'

page = requests.get(url)
content = page.text

convert_string(content)

Comment: Thank you! I opened the file slightly differently:

with open(spanish.txt, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as file: ... etc.